# ¿Como lograr que mi DataGridViewCell personalizado, edite desde la primera tecla presionada?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, datagridview

Soy desarrollador de formación absolutamente autodidacta, pero estoy en fase de terminación de un software de una complejidad relativamente alta, le he llamado **Utilitario Técnico**; mi problema radica, en que como parte de la interfaz de usuario que he diseñado, para evitar tener que repetir el código de validación de los datos introducidos por el usuario, en las múltiples ventanas de captura de datos con que cuenta; diseñé controles de usuario con el código adecuado que impide que el usuario introduzca datos erróneos; además he implementado columnas personalizadas para un `DataGridView` que heredan de `DataGridViewColumn`, estas columnas con `CellTemplate`también implementadas en mi desarrollo que heredan de `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`.
El inconveniente se produce específicamente, en una celda personalizada (`CellTemplate`), que desarrollé a partir de un control de edición (`EditingControl`)que hereda de un control desarrollado por mi, que solo permite que el usuario introduzca valores numéricos, permite definir si el valor es decimal, en cuyo caso permite escribir una sola ves el signo separador decimal, o si es entero no acepta separador decimal, ni ningún otro carácter no numérico, este control hereda de `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`; el pequeño inconveniente que se produce, es que cuando en tiempo de ejecución se selecciona una celda de este tipo, y el usuario presiona una tecla para editar, con la primera tecla presionada se inicia la edición de la celda, pero el valor de la tecla presionada no es capturado por la celda, se requiere presionar la misma tecla por segunda vez para que el valor sea capturado.
Este es el código donde implemento la clase de la celda personalizada `NmrBoxCell` que como ven hereda de `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`

```
public class NmrBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
        {
            public NmrBoxCell()
                : base()
            {
            }
            public NmrBoxCell(Controles_Captura.Tipo_Dato TipoEntrada)
                : base()
            {
            }


            public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
                initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
            {
                base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
                    dataGridViewCellStyle);
                NumrBoxEditControl ctl =
                    DataGridView.EditingControl as NumrBoxEditControl;
                NmrBoxColumn Col = (NmrBoxColumn)this.DataGridView.Columns[this.ColumnIndex];
                ctl.TipoEntrada = Col.TipoEntrada;
                ctl.EditingControlFormattedValue = initialFormattedValue;
            }

            public override Type EditType
            {
                get
                {
                    // Retorna tipo de control NumrBox.
                    return typeof(NumrBoxEditControl);
                }
            }

            public override Type ValueType
            {
                get
                {
                    // Retorna el tipo de valor string.
                    return typeof(string);
                }
            }
            public override object DefaultNewRowValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return base.Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Y esta es la clase `NumrBoxEditControl` donde implemento el control de edición asociado a la celda, que como ven hereda de `IDataGridViewEditingControl` y de `NumericBox.NumericBox` que es el control de usuario desarrollado por mi.

```
   class NumrBoxEditControl : NumericBox.NumericBox, IDataGridViewEditingControl
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        private bool valueChanged = false;
        int rowIndex;
        public NumrBoxEditControl()
            : base()
        {

        }
        //Implementando la propiedad IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue 
        public object EditingControlFormattedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Text; ;
            }
            set
            {

                this.Text = System.Convert.ToString(value);
            }
        }

        // 
        public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
            DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return EditingControlFormattedValue;
        }

        //Implementando el metodo IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl.
        public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
            DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        }

        // 
        public int EditingControlRowIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return rowIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                rowIndex = value;
            }
        }

        //Implementando el metodo IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey 
        public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
            Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.D9:
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.Home:
                case Keys.End:
                case Keys.PageDown:
                case Keys.PageUp:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        //Implementando el metodo IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit 
        public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
            //No necesita hacerse ninguna preparación.
        }

        //Implementando la propiedad IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange.
        public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Implementando la propiedad IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView.
        public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
        {
            get
            {
                return dataGridView;
            }
            set
            {
                dataGridView = value;
            }
        }

        //Implementando la propiedad IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged.
        public bool EditingControlValueChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return valueChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                valueChanged = value;

            }
        }

        //Implementando la propiedad IDataGridViewEditingControlEditingPanelCursor.
        public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Cursor;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            valueChanged = true;
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
            this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        }

    }
```

Disculpen si les resulta extensa la explicación, pero no encontré una manera mas sintetizada de hacerlo, deben tener en cuenta además que soy un desarrollador no profesional y de preparación absolutamente autodidacta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He logrado solucionar el problema planteado en mi pregunta.
**Aclaro que no considero que sea esta la mejor ni mucho menos la única solución**, expongo la solución que le dí por si le pudiera resultar útil a cualquier otro desarrollador, pero agradeceria que cualquier otro colaborador me sugiriera otra solución más simple o más efectiva que la actual.
Para lograr que después de recibir el foco, en una celda del `DataGridView` al presionar la primera tecla, su valor sea capturado por la celda y se realicen los cambios que espera el usuario, implementé que en el evento `EditingControlWantsInputKey` de la clase `NumrBoxEditControl` se asigne el texto al control de edición `NumrBoxEditControl`, pero la asignación en este evento, solo debe realizarse cuando se presiona la primera tecla después de inicializada la edición en la celda, para lograrlo agregué la propiedad `InicializandoEditingControl` al control `NumericBox`, la que se asigna a `true` al inicializar el control y se asigna a `false`, después del primer cambio.
Pero hacer esto introduce un nuevo problema y es que cuando la celda que tiene el foco, entra en modo de edición no por que se presionó una tecla, si no por que se hiso click con el mouse sobre ella, entonces recibiría la adición del texto correspondiente a la celda presionada en dos ocasiones, una ves por la modificación de texto implementada en el método `EditingControlWantsInputKey` y una vez más por el código interno del control `TextBox` que es base de mi control `NumericBox`, que en este caso recibe el evento de la tecla presionada, lograndose el desagradable efecto de que el valor de la tecla presionada se inserta dos veces en el texto de la celda; para evitar que esto ocurra, en la clase del control `NumericBox` coloque la variable local `suspenKeyEvent`, que le indica que en este caso el evento de la tecla presionada debe ser cancelado.

A continuación los procedimientos y propiedades en los que realicé cambios en la clase `NumrBoxEditControl`.

```
class NumrBoxEditControl : NumericBox.NumericBox, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
  private DataGridView dataGridView;
  private bool valueChanged = false;
  private int rowIndex;
  public NumrBoxEditControl()
       : base()
  {
     //Asignación al evento Click del control `NumericBox`
     //Con este evento se establecera adicionalmente la variable InicializandoEditingControl a false para evitar que se asigne texto en el metodo EditingControlWantsInputKey
     base.Click += new EventHandler(NumrBoxEditControl_Click);
  }

  //Implementando el metodo DataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey 
 public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        if ((key >= Keys.D0 && key <= Keys.D9) ||
            (key >= Keys.NumPad0 && key <= Keys.NumPad9))
        {
            //Condicional que verifica si es la primera tecla presionada despues de inicializar
            if (this.InicializandoEditingControl)
            {
                int posicInic = this.SelectionStart;
                //Si existe texto seleccionado se elimina el mismo
                if (this.SelectionLength > 0)
                {
                    this.Text = this.Text.Remove(posicInic, this.SelectionLength);
                }
                //Se inserta el texto de la tecla presionada en la posición del cursor
               //Sustituyo la linea this.Text = this.Text.Insert(posicInic, key.ToString()) por la siguiente.
                this.Text = this.Text.Insert(posicInic, Calculador.Caracteres.ConvertirKeys.KeyCodeToString(key));
                this.SelectionStart = posicInic + 1;
                this.SelectionLength = 0;
                //Se establece a false la propiedad InicializandoEditingControl, evitando que en sucecivas teclas presionadas se ejecute el codigo despues de la condicional 
                this.InicializandoEditingControl = false;
                //Se establece a true la variable SuspendKeyEvent para evitar que se inserte el texto dos veces. 
                this.SuspendKeyEvent = true;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
    }  
 //Evento Click del control NumrBoxEdit, será lanzado si el usuario hace click, despues de iniciada la edición de la celda   
 void NumrBoxEditControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (this.InicializandoEditingControl)
        this.InicializandoEditingControl = false;
 }
```

}

Procedimientos en la clase `NmrBoxCell`

```
public class NmrBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
   public NmrBoxCell()
         : base()
         {
         }

         public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
         {
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
            NumrBoxEditControl ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as NumrBoxEditControl;
            NmrBoxColumn Col = (NmrBoxColumn)this.DataGridView.Columns[this.ColumnIndex];
             ctl.TipoEntrada = Col.TipoEntrada;
             //Llamada al procedimiento InicializarEditingControl del control de usuario NumericBox
            //Se le pasa como argumento el valor de la celda actual
             ctl.InicializarEditingControl(this.Value);
         }
}
```

Procedimientos en el control `NumericBox`, aclaro que solo se incluyen los procedimentos relacionados con la solución al problema planteado en la pregunta, otros procedimiento relacionados con la implementación del control de usuario `NumericBox` no han sido incluidos, para no hacer demasiado extensa la respuesta.

```
public partial class NumericBox : UserControl
{
   bool inicEditControl = false, suspenKeyEvent;


       /// <summary>
        /// Propiedad que indica que el control ha sido inicializado
        /// como control de edición IDataGridViewEditingControl
        /// </summary>
        public bool InicializandoEditingControl
        {
            get { return this.inicEditControl; }
            set { this.inicEditControl = value; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Propiedad que indica si los eventos de entrada de teclas deben ser anulados
        /// </summary>
        public bool SuspendKeyEvent
        {
            get { return this.suspenKeyEvent; }
            set { this.suspenKeyEvent = value; }
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inicializa el control como control de edición IDataGridViewEditingControl
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Valor de entrada de la celda asociada al control de edición IDataGridViewEditingControl</param>
    public void InicializarEditingControl(string value)
    {
        this.inicEditControl = true;
        this.textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Inicializa el control como control de edición IDataGridViewEditingControl
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Valor de entrada de la celda asociada al control de edición IDataGridViewEditingControl</param>
    public void InicializarEditingControl(object value)
    {
        //Se establece la variable local inicEditControl a true, indicando que se acaba de inicializar el control
        this.inicEditControl = true;
        //Se asigna valor al control de edición
        this.textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Evento KeyPress asociado al control textBox1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char decmlSeprtr = System.Convert.ToChar(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator);
        if (e.KeyChar == decmlSeprtr | e.KeyChar == 46 | e.KeyChar == 44)
        {
            e.KeyChar = System.Convert.ToChar(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator);
        }
        if (nonNumberEntered)
        {
            //Se detiene el carácter presionado por no ser un valor numerico.
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (this.suspenKeyEvent)
        {
            //Se detiene el evento de la tecla presionada pues su valor 
            //ya ha sido asignado a la propiedad Text del control textBox1
            e.Handled = true;
            //Se asigna la variable suspenKeyEvent a false, para que no se supriman
            //mas eventos de teclas presionadas
            this.suspenKeyEvent = false;
        }
        this.nonKeyPress = false;
        this.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
        /// <summary>
    /// Evento KeyUp asociado al control textBox1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.suspenKeyEvent)
        {
            //Se detiene el evento de la tecla presionada pues su valor 
            //ya ha sido asignado a la propiedad Text del control textBox1
            e.Handled = true;
            //Se asigna la variable suspenKeyEvent a false, para que no se supriman
            //mas eventos de teclas presionadas
            this.suspenKeyEvent = false;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal || e.KeyValue == 188 || e.KeyValue == 190)
        {
            if (!nonNumberEntered && this.nonKeyPress)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text=this.textBox1.Text+
                    System.Convert.ToChar(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator);
                this.textBox1.SelectionStart = this.textBox1.Text.Length;
            }
        }

        this.OnKeyUp(e);
    }
}
```

Con esta solución se ha logrado que las celdas de la columna personalizada de tipo `NmrBoxColumn` tengan un comportamiento similar al resto de las celdas, especialmente de las celdas de tipo `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución al problema que he planteado en mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Se trata de lograr que la celda que recibe el foco, entre en modo de edición en el mismo momento que lo recibe; con lo cual, cuando se presione la primera tecla los cambios se realizan desde la primera vez sin el efecto planteado en la pregunta.
Para ello implementé el evento `CellEnter` del `DataGridView` de la siguiente forma:

```
    void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is ColumnasDataGridView.NmrBoxCell)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }
```

Esta solución evita el problema planteado, los cambios en la celda se realizan desde la primera tecla que se presiona, pero este comportamiento no me es satisfactorio, ya que las celdas de la columna de tipo `NmrBoxCell`, tendrían un comportamiento diferente al del resto de las columnas, pues siempre que se reciba el foco, la celda entraría en modo de edición, lo cual no es así en las celdas de tipo `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, ni otras similares; aunque esta solución es mucho más simple que la anterior, no es mi preferida por el comportamiento descrito; el foco puede llegar a la celda por que el usuario haga click de manera involuntaria sobre ella, por presionar las teclas de desplazamiento o por que al terminar de editar una celda adyacente se presione la tecla enter, llevando el foco a la celda de tipo `NmrBoxCell`, es decir, no siempre que la celda recibe el foco, es por que el usuario tenga la intención de editar su contenido; que la celda entre en modo de edición sin que sea la intención del usuario, no me parece un comportamiento elegante. No obstante publico la respuesta, por si a algún usuario de este sitio le puada resultar útil.